# Speed Up Adsl in D-Link DSL-2750U

Tags: internet, adsl

I have a `D-Link DSL-2750U` adsl modem router, it shows me my Upstream is 1291 Kbps and my Downstream is 4095 Kbps, but download speed is only 20 KB/s, is there any way to change configuration to speed up my wan connection? As a note `D-Link DSL-2750U` is able to put and get config file using tftp protocol which I tried to change config file and no luck, any idea?

Comment: How do you measure your speed?
Try to `ping` your provider's dns server to see if there is a packet loss (with 1 kbyte packets, for example)

Comment: Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=273ms TTL=44
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=282ms TTL=44
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=270ms TTL=44
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=375ms TTL=43

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I told about that how I measure my speed, downstream speed is 4095 Kilo bit per second but my download speed is 20 Kilo byte per second.

Comment: Speed measurement can be done using say speedtest.net or http://www.dslreports.com/stest  DSLREPORTS also has some additional testing tools.  You can use several such sites to see if there is a common issue

Comment: You can try to download some torrent (for example, ubuntu.iso) to check your speed.
If it is still slow, check:
1) Connect modem without splitter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_filter) and try again
2) Traffic limitation from your provider
3) Your current tariff's speed
4) If above does not help, you can ask your provider to change your adsl profile on their hardware(DSLAM).

Comment: ISP user panel can say that, no needed a website like speedtest.net

Comment: @Mjbmr: So did you measure your download speed?